# Bind odometer to Datalist or gidview

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, css

I downloaded Odometer Sample from http://uvumitools.com/odometer.html
but only the First Element in the Datalist getting the Odometer, others not Displaying the 
Ododmeter.
 Here is the code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/UvumiOdometer-compressed.js"> </script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/uvumi-odometer.css"
<script type="text/javascript">
  var odo2 = new UvumiOdometer('odometer2', { digits: 3 });
</script>`
```

`<asp:DataList ID="dlEquipment" runat="server" DataKeyField="Device_Id"
     RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatColumns="5" Width="100 >
     <ItemTemplate>
    <div id="odometer2<%# Eval("count")%>
    </div></ItemTemplate>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is because you are using a static id `odometer2` in a list element, ID in a document should be unique else the `document.getElementById(id)` will always return the first element with the given id.

if you are using jQuery you can add a class attribute to the `div`

```
<ItemTemplate> <div class="odometer2"> </div></ItemTemplate>
```

then

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($){
    $('.odometer2').each(function(){
        new UvumiOdometer(this, { digits: 3 });
    })
})
</script>
```

Comment: the code working fine on google chrome but internet explorer 9 is not supporting this code